# Using the plural for uncountable nouns

Tags: nouns, plurals

I found a reference to plural of uncountable nouns in Nombro ĉe O-vortoj, which says:

> Multaj O-vortoj estas nomoj de neindividuecaj aŭ substancecaj aferoj, kiuj ne povas esti nombrataj. Oni ne parolas pri unu aŭ pluraj, sed pri pli aŭ malpli multe: akvo, lakto, rizo, metalo, sablo, muziko, veturado, atendado.
>
> Tiaj O-vortoj normale ne ricevas J-finaĵon, ĉar la distingo inter unu-nombro kaj multe-nombro estas fremda al ili. Sed iafoje oni parolas pri diversaj specoj de ia neindividueca afero. Tiam oni povas je bezono uzi J-finaĵon:
>
> - metalo → metaloj = pluraj specoj de metalo
> - muziko → muzikoj = pluraj specoj de muziko
> - Hejme li regalas sin per dolĉaj bonegaj vinoj. Temas pri pluraj specoj de dolĉa vino.
> - Krom la Eŭklida geometrio eblas elpensi aliajn geometriojn kun aliaj reguloj. Oni parolas pri diversaj geometri-sistemoj.

I can understand using *metaloj*, since we use it already in Italian, but  because in Italian *metallo* is a countable noun (*un metallo*, *due metalli*). I can also understand using *musikoj* since in Italian we use the plural too, but to mean the works of a composer.

Can I use *akvoj* to say [*international waters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_waters) or *internal waters*? Can I say *neĝoj* to mean the snow fallen on different events, such as in *the snows of Kilimanjaro*?

Comment: Since you mention Italian, I'd like to just add that in Bulgarian all of these pluralities are normal (and so I would believe in other Slavic languages, although I do not know for sure), so Esperanto is not some kind of exception.

Comment: The problem with Esperanto is that it is not possible to assign it a language family. Some _characteristics_ are taken from a language, and others from other languages. For example, which vowel is accented is very similar to Italian, even though Italian has more complex rules for that.

Comment: Of course. And the question is very good. I just gave a hint to where this particular concept might have come from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The examples you give, *neĝoj* and *akvoj*, are quite common, and you will also encounter *ĉieloj, sabloj, eternoj*.